# Building RXTX with --disable-locks

Tags: rxtx

I need to build RXTX (http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for a 64 bit platform with --disable-locks. ( the target platform is a Ubuntu Snappy platform so there is a problem with the permissions and lock files).

The .configure --disable-locks and make seemed to run ok.
I got a new .jar file and librxtxSerial.so as a result.

However when I installed them, I get the following error :
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.nativeGetVersion()Ljava/lang/String; thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

Is there something else I need to do?
Are there other object files I need to copy over.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.
The problem was that the configure script was not expecting a java version higher than 1.5 as shown here in t he extract :

case $JAVA_VERSION in
    1.2*|1.3*|1.4*|1.5*)
        #fix_parameters $JPATH/jre/lib/javax.comm.properties
        CLASSPATH=".:\$(TOP):\$(TOP)/src:"`find $JPATH/ -name RXTXcomm.jar |head -n1`
        RXTX_PATH="\$(JPATH)/jre/lib/\$(OS_ARCH)"
        JHOME=$JPATH/"jre/lib/ext"

So the paths were not being set up correctly for me.

I changed it to 
case $JAVA_VERSION in
    1.2*|1.3*|1.4*|1.5*|1.7*)

Then it worked ok.